# Missing areas when using mosaic after projectRaster or vice versa

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, modis, mosaic

I have 290 MODIS NPP tif tiles that I want to merge and project into EPSG 4326. mosaic_raster() works just fine (Fig 1) but when I project the global raster (with or without a template) I lose almost all the southern areas (Fig 2).

Fig 1 [image: Areas before reprojecting] Fig 2 [image: Areas missing after reprojection].

Fig1 metadata[image]

Fig2 metadata:crs correct, also this ext would be sufficient[image]

The data has been acquired from [here](https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov/search/granules?p=C1631984056-LPDAAC_ECS!C1299783630-LPDAAC_ECS&q=C1631984056-LPDAAC_ECS&m=41.253662109375!-77.34375!7!1!0!&ac=true&tl=1573709015!4!!) and the original crs is

+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs

For merging I used mosaic_raster as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876591/merging-multiple-rasters-in-r)

```
e <- extent(-180,180,-90,90) 
epsg4326 <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
template <- raster(e)
projection(template) <- epsg4326
writeRaster(template,
            file="MyBigNastyRasty.tif",
            format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE ) 
mosaic_rasters(gdalfile=my_rastlist,
               dst_dataset="MyBigNastyRasty.tif",      of="GTiff")
```

and  for reprojecting

```
npp_ <- raster("~/MyBigNastyRasty.tif")
npp_reproj <- projectRaster(npp, crs=epsg4326)
```

Same results if I use **templateraster** with correct res and crs inside the projectRaster.

I also tried to project every tiff tile first and then merging, but then I had a different origin. To tackle this, I tried to use the one global **templateraster** when projecting the tiles. However, then it took 25hours for 290 tiff files although I used 6 cores in beginCluster()!

For this, I used code

```
rlist <- lapply(my_rastlist, raster)
beginCluster()
npp_individual_reproj <- lapply(rlist, function(r) {projectRaster(r, templateraster)})
endCluster()
```

**Any ideas what is wrong?**

Comment: Is there some way I can get from that source data link to your 290 tiff files? When I go there the "Download all" button has "5,800 granules". Alternatively, can you give more details of the raster in Fig 1 - show its summary information? Just for clarity `npp_` is Fig 1 and `npp_reproj` is Fig 2 with the south cut off?

Comment: Dear Spacedman, There are 5800 granules for the total time period (20y) so 290 files for one year. These were downloaded using “cygwin” software and converted to tif files using R. I added the pictures of the summary information to the post above.

Comment: Any new ideas or help for this problem?